# what are the Token in solr 5.3.1 features?

Tags: solr, lucene, token, text-processing

the class `Token` in `lucene 4.3` has been replaced with Token ( `org.apache.solr.parser.Token`) in `solr 5.3.1`. the question is what do the features `beginColumn`, `beginLine`, `endColumn`, `endLine` mean? in fact in this new class how we can calculate the Token length, or begin_offset and end_offset?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the Token classes. The Lucene Token class was deprecated for the TokenStream interface after 2.9. The `org.apache.solr.parser.Token` class is used for parsing the actual query submitted (the syntax of the query), as Solr has certain custom formats.